# What was a shtar (document) for?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, legal-documents, borrowing

It seems that a possible prerequisite of knowing [What recourse is available for someone whose property was seized by a creditor of the seller?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68246/what-recourse-is-available-for-someone-whose-property-was-seized-by-a-creditor-o) is knowing what happened to a loan document?

When someone lent money with document and witnesses, what then happened to the document? Did the loaner hold onto it, or was it placed in public storage for anyone to look up?
Did it depend on local custom?

Feel free to answer for other kind of documents besides loans.

Answer (score 2):

The standard behavior was for the loaner to hold on to the document, and then present it to *beit din* when the appropriate time arrived (the *halacha* requires either the borrower or the witnesses to testify to it being valid).

A few examples:

- [הוציא עליו שטר מקויים](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%92)
- [שמא ימות ונמצא השטר ביד היורש וגובה בו את הרבית](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%94_%D7%99)
- [לוה שכתב שטר בכתב ידו והעיד בו עדים ונתנו למלוה](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%91)